# not working notificactioncompat with firebase

Tags: android, web-services, rest, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I don't know but my notification not show.. only see message with Log Consola Android Studio u.u

```
public class MyFcmListenerService extends com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService {
public static final String TAG = MyFcmListenerService.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Log.d(TAG,"HECHO");
    Log.d(TAG,remoteMessage.getData().get("message"));
    Log.d(TAG, "token_test_"+Test.getTest(1).getToken_test());
    if (Test.getTest(1).isEstado_token()) {
        Log.d(TAG,"bolean1"+String.valueOf(Test.getTest(1).isEstado_token()));
        mostrarMensaje(remoteMessage.getData().get("message"));
    }
}

private void mostrarMensaje(String mensaje) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(Constantes.PREFERENCIA_PARA_PREGUNTAS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int pre_token_count = preferences.getInt(Constantes.KEY_IDENTIFICADOR, 0);

    Intent i = new Intent(this, PrincipalActivity.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,i,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle("TEST")
            .setContentText(mensaje)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setVibrate(new long[]{2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000});

    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    manager.notify(pre_token_count, builder.build());

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    pre_token_count++;
    editor.putInt(Constantes.KEY_IDENTIFICADOR, pre_token_count);
    editor.commit();

}
```

}

My message is this "Bien joven :D"..
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLSXY.png)

fawfaw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Required) indicates a Notification is required to have an icon:

> A Notification object must contain the following:
>
> - A small icon, set by `setSmallIcon()`
> - A title, set by `setContentTitle()`
> - Detail text, set by `setContentText()`

Add an icon to your notification with [setSmallIcon()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setSmallIcon(int)).